# setting up app.js using git bash error

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am a beginner for this one and I want to learn from the start. I want to set up app.js in my sp-node-mysql directory to use mysql through javascript. But I can't get through.

Here is the line of code: `var mysql = require("mysql");`

and the error: `bash: syntax error near unexpected token '('`

I think there is nothing wrong with the line of code. But it is still showing this error message.

Comment: have you run "npm init" and "npm install mysql" already?  Also, are you executing your program by typing "node app"?

Comment: hello I am done installing mysql through npm, but I didn't run npm init, I'll try it now. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get started do the following:

In your projects root directory type the following into the command line:

"npm init"

"npm install mysql --save"

This will create a package.json file and a node_modules folder in your projects root directory. Within the node_modules folder you will have the mysql module installed.  Nothing else needs to be done with this.

Then in the project root directory create a file called app.js.

Within app.js write the following code.

```
var mysql = require('mysql')
console.log('No errors during require')
process.exit()
```

Then execute your node program by typing "node app" or "node app.js" on the command line within your projects root folder.

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: It was successful! Thank you!

Comment: it would be better if you type: `npm install mysql -S` this would also update your dependencies in **package.json**